# How can my proof of the $\Delta L = \frac{d_1 d_2}{L} \sin\alpha \Delta\alpha$ triangle property be improved?

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, trigonometry, approximation

The *Exercises for The Feynman Lectures on Physics* (New Millenium Edition 2014) asks the reader to prove the following formula in exercise 2.4 (a) pg. 2-1:
$$\Delta L = \frac{d_1 d_2}{L} \sin\alpha \Delta\alpha \quad(1)$$
where $d_1$ & $d_2$ correspond to the fixed lengths of a triangle, $\alpha$ is the angle between $d_1$ & $d_2$, and *L* is the length of the side opposite to $\alpha$ whose length varies by $\Delta L$ when $\alpha$ is varied by a small amount, $\Delta\alpha$.

I attempted to find a justification by applying the law of cosines &  varying a starting angle, $\alpha_1$, by $\Delta \alpha$:

Let $\ L_1$ correspond to the length of *L* associated with angle $\alpha_1$ and $\ L_2$ correspond to the length of *L* associated with angle $\alpha_2$. Then
$$
\ {L_2}^2 - {L_1}^2 = d_1^2 + d_2^2 -2d_1d_2\cos\alpha_2-(d_1^2 + d_2^2 -2d_1d_2\cos\alpha_1) \\ (L_2-L_1)(L_2+L_1) = -2d_1d_2\cos\alpha_2+2d_1d_2\cos\alpha_1 \\ L_2-L_1 = \frac{2 d_1 d_2}{L_2+L_1} (\cos\alpha_1-\cos\alpha_2) \quad (2).
$$
Since $\Delta\alpha$ is small, $L_2 \approx L_1$ and thus $L_2+L_1=2L_1$, or simply $2L$. Also, $L_2-L_1$ in (2) can be rewritten as $\Delta L$ to give
$$
\Delta L = \frac{d_1 d_2}{L} (\cos\alpha_1-\cos\alpha_2) \quad (3).
$$
These are my questions:
Can the difference of cosines in (3)  be rewritten using identities and/or small angle approximations to match (1)?
Is there an algebra error? Or a brand new approach is needed?

Comment: You have $\alpha_2 = \alpha_1 + \Delta \alpha$. Use a Taylor expansion.

Comment: You can also write $$\cos(\alpha_1)-\cos(\alpha_2)=2\sin\left(\frac{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{\alpha_2-\alpha_1}{2}\right)\,,$$ and then use $\sin(\theta)\approx \theta$ for any small angle $\theta$.

Comment: The easiest way of all is to start with $L^2=d_1^2+d_2^2-2d_1d_2\cos\alpha$, and then take the derivative of this equation with respect to $\alpha$ to get $\dfrac{\Delta L}{\Delta \alpha}\approx \dfrac{\text{d}L}{\text{d}\alpha}$.

Comment: @Batominovski Thanks for your approach. Using the sum and difference formula for cosine and the α2=α1+Δα substitution suggested by Winther gives the formula, but you need to imagine that cosα1−cosα1cosΔα is 0, which is a bit far-fetched.

Comment: @Batominovski silly question, but if you apply $\frac{d}{d\alpha}$ to $L^2$ how do you handle that? $\frac{dL^2}{d\alpha}$?

Answer (score 2):

We can use the following trigonometric identity of the sum of two angles.
$$\cos\left(\alpha_2\right)=\cos\left(\alpha_1 + \Delta\alpha\right) = \cos\left(\alpha_1\right)\cos\left(\Delta\alpha\right)-\sin\left(\alpha_1\right)\sin\left(\Delta\alpha\right)$$

For $\Delta\alpha\rightarrow 0$, We know that $\space\cos\left(\Delta\alpha\right)\rightarrow 1\space$  and $\space\sin\left(\Delta\alpha\right)\rightarrow \Delta\alpha$.

Therefore, the above equation can be written as,
$$\cos\left(\alpha_2\right)=cos\left(\alpha_1\right)-\sin\left(\alpha_1\right)\Delta\alpha.$$

Now, substitute this value of $\cos\left(\alpha_2\right)$ into your equation (3) to get,

$$\Delta L = \frac{d_1 d_2}{L} \Big(\cos\left(\alpha_1\right)-\cos\left(\alpha_2\right)\Big)=\frac{d_1 d_2}{L} \Big(\cos\alpha_1-cos\left(\alpha_1\right)+\sin\left(\alpha_1\right)\Delta\alpha\Big)$$
$$\qquad\quad\qquad=\frac{d_1 d_2}{L} \sin\left(\alpha_1\right)\Delta\alpha.$$